# Can I perform hajj given that I have a mortgage?

Tags: hajj, mortgage

I bought a house using mortgage and I'm planning to go for Hajj within 2 to 3 years. Will I be allowed to go for hajj if I'm still paying monthly house mortgage together with my husband?

Comment: Why do you think you would be barred from going to Hajj?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do Hajj even if you have mortgage. If you are dealing with riba, then it is a big sin. But a sin does not prevent a Muslim from going for Hajj.

Edits:

Let me elaborate on this.

**For loans,** if the lender is after my life to payoff my loan, then if I have money I must pay the lender and not use that for Hajj. But in mortgages, the minimum requirement is to pay the monthly installment and if this is done then the rest of the money can be used for Hajj.

After this comes the mention of sin. Interest-bearing loan is not illegal in most countries, but this is a sin in Islam. That sin is not preventing one from going to Hajj.

Hope this clear.

Also see AMJA answer on a similar question - http://www.amjaonline.org/fatwa-76815/info

(AMJA is a reputed fatwa giving org in USA)

Comment: Now I added more clarification with a reference. Thanks.